# does repeated k-folds give a confidence interval?

Tags: t-test, svm

I have 3 sets of data from one experimental condition and 2 sets of data from another. I would like to compare the classification accuracy when using data from each condition to train an SVM classifier. If I do 5-fold CV and take the mean accuracy for each dataset, I end up with 3 points for one condition and 2 for the other, which doesn't provide enough samples for a t-test. 
I thought I might get around this by bootstrapping a confidence interval for each dataset, and getting a bootstrapped significance out of that. is this at all correct, or are there other ways to get the statistical significance of the comparison?